# Objective C, Copy resource file from main bundle to documents: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 The file doesn’t exist."

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager, file-copying, nsbundle

Here I want to achieve a function which can copy a res file from main bundle (which is added manually from Mac Finder to Xcode project ) (Fig 1) to Document Folder.

[Click here to see the Xcode project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWAta.png)

And to achieve that goal, I use NSFileManager. Here is the function code:

```
- (void)addCamConfig {
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *destPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:CAM_CONFIG];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destPath]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam" ofType:@"yaml"];
    BOOL ret = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"cam_ret:%d\nsourcePath:%@\ndestPath:%@\nerror:%@",ret,sourcePath,destPath,error.description);
    }
}
```

}

In that case, sourcePath and destPath are both ensured not to be nil.

But strange thing happened in the first time, "copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:&error" return "NO" and error log showed below:

> cam_ret:0
> sourcePath:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DF49723-E11D-4D67-AD0F-39C2B82B80A4/NitroDemo.app/cam.yaml
> destPath:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/181F8B72-402B-4D0C-91D5-0D9759BC607E/Documents/nitro/cam.yaml
> error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “cam.yaml” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DF49723-E11D-4D67-AD0F-39C2B82B80A4/NitroDemo.app/cam.yaml, NSUserStringVariant=(
> ), NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/181F8B72-402B-4D0C-91D5-0D9759BC607E/Documents/nitro/cam.yaml, NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DF49723-E11D-4D67-AD0F-39C2B82B80A4/NitroDemo.app/cam.yaml, NSUnderlyingError=0x2826476f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Surprisingly, when I run project second time, the error disappeared, "copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:&error" return "YES".

And if I remove this app from my iPhone, then rebuild the project , reinstall and run the app first time, the same error message appears again. And as I expected, when I run the project second time, the error disappeared.

So I wonder what exactly happened in the first time and second time?

====================

**UPDATE:** I solved this problem by creating an intermediate folder `nitro`.

The key point here is that, as you may not noticed in the log, the dest path `XXX/Documents/nitro/cam.yaml` contains a not existed intermediate folder `nitro`. So in the first time when I call `copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:&error`, it fails and may create that folder (just for my guess). As a result, when I run second time, the `copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:&error` returns YES.

Comment: You might want to make sure that a 'Copy Files Phase' is present in your project configuration, in the 'Build Phases' tab. Otherwise, the file will not be copied into your compiled application's bundle.

Comment: @LinChiSin This does not make sense - can you give more code e.g. show where / when you copy it.

Comment: @G.Morin YES, the res file is ensure to be copied in application bundle as you can see the source path is correct. And I already solved this problem as descripted in UPDATE. Thx!

Comment: @skaak problem solved. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the update you could solve it then by inserting something like below.

```
                [NSFileManager.defaultManager createDirectoryAtPath:newDir
                            withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                     attributes:nil
                                          error:NULL];
```